# Javascript clock using certain time zone

Tags: javascript, time, clock, zone

I have the following javascript function that works as it should, however it should only display the time in CST (GMT-5) regardless of what the viewer's time zone is. How can I modify it to do that?

```
function updateClock () {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var currentHours = currentTime.getHours();
    var currentMinutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var currentSeconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

    currentMinutes = (currentMinutes < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentMinutes;
    currentSeconds = (currentSeconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + currentSeconds;

    var timeOfDay = (currentHours < 12) ? "AM" : "PM";
    currentHours = (currentHours > 12) ? currentHours-12 : currentHours;
    currentHours = (currentHours == 0) ? 12 : currentHours;

    var currentTimeString = currentHours + ":" + currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds + " " + timeOfDay;

    document.getElementById("clock").firstChild.nodeValue = currentTimeString;
}
```

Comment: try moment js http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I am looking to simply modify the above code - not use a completely different library. Thanks though!